# Converting GWT logic into angular

Tags: angular

Below is the snippet of code written in GWT , I need to migrate this code to angular. THe reason i am using a timer here is that Method 1 is initializing the thread and starting it. The main scope for this is to check the thread is completed and then I am able to export the file.

```
method1(params, function(e:Result):void {
                    var t:Timer = new Timer(1000, 1);
                    
                    progressBar.minimum = 0;
                    computing = true;
                    t.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, function (event:TimerEvent):void {
                        someCall(params, function (e:Result):void {
                            some logic
    
                            if (checking whether the file is created ot not) {
                                
                                if (exportResult.filesProcessed < exportResult.fileCount) {
                                    some logic to appear the progress bar 
                                } else {
                                    export the data
                                }
                            }
                            
                            if (computing) {
                                t.reset();
                                t.start();
                            }
                        });
                    });
                    t.start();
            

    });
```

I am using setInterval and it is going in infinite loop , it is not waiting for the export action to be completed and then downloading the file.

```
setInterval(() => {
            Method1.subscribe((res) => {
                console.log(' export file completed: ' + res);
                
            });
        }, 1000);
```